# How is this Rails routing working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had a `link_to` that would create paths like `domain.com/shopname`. It looked like this:

**routes.rb**

`get 'shop/:username' => 'users#profile'`

**index.html.erb**

`<%= link_to user.shop_name, user.username %>`

However, I wanted the path to be `domain.com/shops/shopname`, and I ended up with this:

**routes.rb**

`get 'shop/:username' => 'users#profile', :as => :shop`

**index.html.erb**

`<%= link_to user.shop_name, shop_path(user.username) %>`

It works, but I don't understand why!

Comment: It works because you're using it exactly as designed. I'm not sure how to really explain it, do you just want a dump of the source code? You're using `routes.rb` to build a helper method which which outputs a relative URL. What part is confusing? The entire routing process, the creation of `shop_path`, what? This question is unanswerable and off-topic as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you understand how routing works...

When you use `as:`, you're defining a *named* path, which gets an associated helper method.

The whole point of the helper is to fill in the "blanks" in a route. Your route, `/shop/:username`, has one blank, `:username`. So, the first argument you pass to `shop_path` is filled in for the `:username` variable.

Lets assume your `user.username` is `"john"`.

It wasn't working *before* because you were just dumping a string into `link_to`, which spits out a path like `/john`. That obviously won't match `/shop/:username`. When you give `"john"` to `shop_path`, it spits out `/shop/john`, which *will* match the route `/shop/:username`.